# Cadastro usando php e mysql

Tags: php

Boa noite.

Criei um sistema de cadastro que está funcionando. 
O que acontece é quando eu cadastro um usuário, ele fica no banco mas quando eu recarrego ou volto uma pagina é adicionado outro usuário fantasma(porque não aparece nada) no banco,será que é por causa de algum erro na minha programação?

```
<?php
header("Content-type:text/html; charset=utf8");
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Olaaaaaaas</title>
    <link rel="shortocut icon" type="image/png" href="img/logo.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<?php  
    if  (isset($_POST['nome']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['turno']) && isset($_POST['horas']) && isset($_POST['entrada']));
    {

        $nome    = $_POST['nome'];
        $email   = $_POST['email'];
        $turno   = $_POST['turno'];
        $horas   = $_POST['horas'];
        $entrada = $_POST['entrada'];

        try {
            $username = 'root';
            $password = '';
          $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=tabela', $username, $password);
          $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

          $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO cronograma VALUES(:codigo,:nome,:email,:turno,:horas,:entrada)');
          $stmt->execute(array(

            ':codigo' => null,
            ':nome' => $nome,
            ':email' => $email,
            ':turno' => $turno,
            ':horas' => $horas,
            ':entrada' => $entrada,      
          ));

          if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) //verifica que o insert foi executado
          {
            echo "<script>alert('funcionario cadastrado');</script>";
          } 
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
          echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }

    }
?>
    <h1>Cadastrar</h1>

    <form method="POST" action="">
        <label>Nome</label><br>
        <input class="oi" type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Nome do trabalhador"><br>

        <label>Email</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email do trabalhador"><br>

        <label>Turno</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="turno" placeholder="Turno do trabalhador"><br>

        <label>Horas</label><br>
        <input type="num" name="horas" placeholder="horas de contribuição"><br>

        <label>Entrada</label><br>
        <input type="num" name="entrada" placeholder="Inicio na empresa"><br>

        <br><input type="submit">
    </form>

    <table class="table table-dark">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">codigo</th>
    <th scope="col">Nome</th>
    <th scope="col">Entrada</th>
    <th scope="col">E-mail</th>
    <th scope="col">turno</th>
    <th scope="col">Horas de contribuição</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php  
    try {                
      $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM cronograma');
      $stmt->execute();

      //carrega os dados do banco
      $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

      //imprime os dados do banco
      foreach ($result as $registro => $dados) {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>' . $dados['codigo'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $dados['nome'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $dados['email'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $dados['turno'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $dados['horas'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $dados['entrada'] . '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
      }

      echo 'Foram encontrado(s) '.$stmt->rowCount().' registro(s)'; 
        }   catch(PDOException $e) {
      echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
      }
  ?>          
  </tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

e o meu banco de dados é "tabela"

Tabela:

```
cronograma{
  codigo int auto_increment,
  nome varchar 100,
  turno varchar 100,
  horas varchar 100,
  entrada varchar 100,
  email varchar 100,
}
```

Comment: Você está colocando o comando de inserir na mesma página. Sugiro criar outra página só com o código do PHP de inserção. No final você pode voltar para a página do formulário usando ```header("Location: http://pagina.com.br/formulario.php");```

Comment: Ou limpar as variáveis após dar o insert no banco: ```$_POST['nome'] = "";``` Dessa forma ele não executaria ao recarregar a página. Nesse caso precisa não apenas checar se as variáveis estão criadas com o ```ìf (isset...```, mas se estão preenchidas também.